# How to replace multiple string responses in multiple columns

Tags: r, stringr

I have imported a csv dataset with many columns and many responses. I want to look at specific columns and replace a set of responses.

In my dataset, I have: hairtypeDad, hairtypeMom, hairtypeBro1, hairtypeSis1, which are all located in different areas of my file. Within these are many responses that I want to change, including but not limited to:

```
    Straight= straightened,
    Curly= curled
    Wavy = waved
    wavyy=waved
    cruley= curled
```

and so on.

Below is the code that I have tried so far:

```
    hairdata <- read.csv ('alldata.csv', header = TRUE, stringAsFactors = FALSE)
    hair_vars<- c ("hairtypeDad", "hairtypeMom", "hairtypeBro1", "hairtypeSis1")
    hairdata[hair_vars]<-str_replace_all(hairdata[hair_vars],
c("Straight"= "straightened",
"Curly"= "curled",
"Wavy" = "waved",
"wavyy"= "waved"))

#I also tried:

    hairdata %>% mutate(across(c("hairtypeDad", "hairtypeMom", "hairtypeBro1", "hairtypeSis1"), 
fns= ~ str_replace_all(., 
c("Straight"= "straightened",
"Curly"= "curled", 
"Wavy" = "waved",
"wavyy"= "waved"))
```

Ultimately, I want it to go from:

| id | hairtypeMom | hairtypeDad | hairtypeBro1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Straight | Curly | wavyy |
| 2 | Wavy | Curly | Curly |

to

| id | hairtypeMom | hairtypeDad | hairtypeBro1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | straightened | curled | waved |
| 2 | waved | curled | curled |

and am not getting what i need. Please help!!

Comment: See `?str_replace()` to better understand how the function works. You will have to use the function for each of the changes you want to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close; you were just missing the period in `.fns =`, as you had `fns =`. You were also missing a couple of closing parentheses as well.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(
    c("hairtypeDad", "hairtypeMom", "hairtypeBro1"),
    .fns = ~ str_replace_all(.,
      c("Straight" = "straightened",
        "Curly" = "curled",
        "Wavy" = "waved",
        "wavyy" = "waved")
    )
  ))
```

**Output**

```
  id  hairtypeMom hairtypeDad hairtypeBro1
1  1 straightened      curled        waved
2  2        waved      curled       curled
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, hairtypeMom = c("Straight", "Wavy"), 
    hairtypeDad = c("Curly", "Curly"), hairtypeBro1 = c("wavyy", 
    "Curly")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something but just couldn't figure out what it was!!

Comment: @heemz No problem! You can always just leave off `.fns =` too. As far as readability, the `~` makes it clear that to the right is the function.